# When stepping into class instantiation, eclipse debugger goes to native code

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I recently upgraded to helios and now every time I step into a constructor for a class (e.g. `Cat myCat = new Cat();`), eclipse debugger shows the stack as

[image: java stack trace entering instantiation]:

To get to the actual constructor code, I have to step out several times which is annoying. This is happening with every class and despite the stack I never see any error messages in the console. How do I fix this so it directly steps into the constructor for my class?

This only happens the first time the class is used, and even for classes that are in the same src file as the current one.

Comment: does the class exist? it looks like a ClassNotFoundException is being thrown...

Comment: Class definitely exists, the debugger eventually enters the constructer, and the program successfully runs.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Eclipse has a step filter preference in the Java debugger preferences. Its default preference filters out `java.lang.ClassLoader`, however this wasn't working. This might have something to do with recently having installed and switched to using jre7. To solve my problem I added a filter to step through any code in the `java.lang` package.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I think the ClassNotFoundException is just happening as a part of class loading -- the problem is that you have a breakpoint set to trigger when those exceptions are thrown. My guess is that your version of Eclipse has this breakpoint on by default, whereas the old one didn't.

Check out [this link](http://www.popcornfarmer.com/gamedev/2009/01/eclipse-debug-error/), which reports a similar problem and provides the solution, which is just to disable that breakpoint.

(In the interest of teaching to fish and all that, the google search term was "eclipse debugger launcher$appclassloader".)

Comment: This is indeed the problem and occurs on first invocation of a method on a class that has not yet been loaded.  Just hit F7 (return) as many times as it takes to get back to your class -- I find it usually takes 8 presses of F7 to work back to my class.

Comment: Btw, I wonder if you could also work around this by loading the class before you step into the constructor. For instance, what if you evaluated in your debugger `Class.forName(Cat.class.getName())` ?

Comment: Anything that gets the class loaded will bypass this problem.

Comment: In the breakpoints window i cleared all breakpoints yet this still happens! (btw i googled "Launcher$AppClassLoader java", didn't get any hits.)

Comment: If you step into a constructor with F5, no breakpoint need be involved.  "Step Into" will step into the next instruction.  If you are invoking the constructor and the class is not yet loaded, the next thing to happen is a ClassNotFoundException (so the class can be loaded), so that is what you will step into.

Comment: Ok, the last time i did any serious java programming was in highschool. Has this always been the case?

Comment: @cplusplus Try loading the class before you get to the constructor. I don't use Eclipse, myself, so I can't more detailed than my evaluation trick above. As for the search results, it was adding the "eclipse debugger" keywords that did it for me.

Comment: Eclipse would usually filter out `ClassLoader` code when debugging, for some reason this wasn't working after having upgraded. See my answer for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

From the stack track reported in Eclipse, it seems a `ClassNotFoundException` was initialized and is being thrown, Did the application you wrote ran into any problems?

Have you set breakpoints in constructor of the class?  you was not able to step into the constructor at all?

Were you using `Class.forname()` or import to introduce the class to JRE?

Comment: No problems at all, and I was able to step into the constructor.

Comment: Nothing special to import the class.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the for my students using lab machines running openjdk, the solution was to add a step filter in the same preferences mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/10525351/1449799 but add `jdk.*`