# Eclipse cannot debug a newly created class in a package

Tags: java, eclipse

In Eclipse, I have a Java package in a project that I can debug. I added a new class called Clothing by right-clicking on the package and hitting New->Class.

Now, this  code works. It builds and runs successfully and I can successfully use the Open Declaration function on the window that pops up when I hover over Clothing-related constructors and methods.

However, when I try to debug it by stepping into Clothing, I get a "Source Not Found" and a prompt to edit the Source Lookup Path. The code still works when I step over it.

I'm sure there's a simple setting that I need to turn on or off but how do I debug this class?

Edit: I have cleaned this project, the code is all in one project in my workspace and I have restarted Eclipse multiple times.

Comment: Is the code spread across multiple projects in your workspace? If so, how did you add the dependencies between projects, and/or are these plain Java projects, or are you using Maven to build and/or for dependency management?

Comment: Do you have build project automatically enabled?

Comment: Have you cleaned your project yet?

Comment: @Kathir Build Project Automatically is not enabled but I have tried debugging with it both turned on and off.

Comment: @Aify I have cleaned it multiple times.

Comment: @KevinHooke Code is just one project in my workspace.

Comment: Can you add some screenshots of the steps you take to reproduce this issue?

Comment: Sounds like a job for a simple "exit eclipse, restart, and start eclipse again"

Comment: @KevinWorkman I have restarted Eclipse multiple times.

Comment: Do you have the break point inside Clothing and you get the source not found before hitting that point.

Comment: @joshualan wild shot but : is it possible that you have Clothing class in some library that you built and that your project also depends on ? Check YourProject->JavaBuildPath->Libraries

Comment: @kiruwka Went there and there's nothing there.

Comment: @Kathir No, I have my break point on the line where I call my Clothing constructor. I then try to step in and then it says Source Not Found.

Comment: Is all the code compiled, no compile or project build path errors, anything showing on the Markers or Problems view?. Do you have 'Build Automatically' turned on?

Comment: Is the existing and new source all below a folder in your project that is on the build path (look in project properties, Java Build Path/Source). If your source folder is src (for example) then all your source to be compiled should be below this point.

Comment: @joshualan please see solution I posted and let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

This is *not* because of package/location of your project class, but because you are stepping into **constructor** while instantiating class for the first time.
Even if your class was declared *in the same file* - you'd likely have same problem.

When you instantiate your class for the first time, the class itself is loaded by [java.lang.ClassLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html) first, so your debugger is likely trying to step in ClassLoader's code, which you don't have.

**Solution:**
You can tell your debugger to skip *ClassLoader* part with [Eclipse debug filter preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10525351/2358786) and it should work.