# Eclipse dubber in java

Tags: java, debugging, constructor

I'm trying to debug my program in eclipse but whenever I try to step into a constructor it says, "Source not found", and I saw someone had a similar issue and they said to go to Window->Preferences->Java, then check Step Filter and check all the boxes and then apply, but that's not working. Is anyone familiar with on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Hard to tell without more detail in the question but it may be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10510410/when-stepping-into-class-instantiation-eclipse-debugger-goes-to-native-code

Answer (score 0):

There currently is a bug report open that sounds like it might concern you: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=537699

Try to go to `Java->Debug->Use advanced source lookup` and turn that off